# how to git pull/fetch local repo from remote where cloned with --share --bare

Tags: git

I have a local repo cloned using

```
git clone --share --bare git@remote:foo.git /tmp/share.git
```

so now I can develop/push/pull from local clone at /tmp/share.git

However, how do I **pull or fetch** from **remote:foo.git** at **/tmp/share.git**

Comment: local repo with --bare option???

Comment: @Stephan this is not so unusual, I often make quick local backups of my local repos with this option, and if you're doing Git server administration, the remote repo ***is a local repo*** in that case.

Comment: @Cupcake yes but if he wants to pull and fetch from the remote, he probably wants to work in this repo thus making it a working repo.. he should create that without --bare -probably- the question is very vague

Answer (score 0):

The --bare option means that you are only creating a git repositiory without a working directory, i.e without any of your project files checked out on your disk. You can not directly work on this repository, it can only be used as a remote repository.

Now, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. If you want to work locally, then just use a basic clone:

```
git clone --share --bare git@remote:foo.git /tmp/share.git
```

As far as I understand, you are maybe trying to create a proxy to push / pull from a local tmp directory? It's useless. Remember that Git is a decentralized VCS, so except for push and pull operations, everything happens locally.